# Save part of variable into another variable

Tags: php

I want to find an ID from a variable and save it into another variable. However, this id is in the middle of it all among other numbers, and I don't know how to target it..

```
$f_contents = file("links.txt");
$url = $f_contents[mt_rand(0, count($f_contents) - 1)];

echo $url;

// $url will output something similar to:

// http://store.steampowered.com/app/24010/?snr=1_5_9__400
// or..
// http://store.steampowered.com/app/275200/?snr=1_5_9__400
// or..
// http://store.steampowered.com/app/275830/?snr=1_5_9__400
// and so on.

// $gameid = 24010; (or the other ids)
```

How do I get that ID number after app/ and before /?? 24010, 275200 or 275830 in this particular case.

Comment: You could use regex or `explode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to get the number you want ($gameid) with the function explode.

You should loop in a foreach if $url is an array of url.

```
$url = "http://store.steampowered.com/app/24010/?snr=1_5_9__400";
$answer = explode('/',$url); // Splits the variable at each '/' character in an array named $answer
$gameID = $answer[4]; // Your gameID will always be at this position in the array.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex:

```
$url = 'http://store.steampowered.com/app/24010/?snr=1_5_9__400';
preg_match('~/app/(.*)/~', $url, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; //outputs 24010
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Gonna donate the best answer to the guy with the lower amount of coins though, but they were both working equally well.

Comment: @JohnSmith No problem, glad i could help you. I can live without the tick mark!

Answer (score 2):

Already two perfectly good answers, but here is one other option. Since it is a URL, you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);
```

which will give you an array like this:

```
array (size=4)
  'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'store.steampowered.com' (length=22)
  'path' => string '/app/275200/' (length=12)
  'query' => string 'snr=1_5_9__400' (length=14)
```

Then you can [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) off the 'app' and slashes from the path to get the id.

```
$gameid = trim($parsed['path'], '/app');
```

Comment: Nice answer, didn't think about this one !

Comment: Thanks! I think there's almost always more than one way to do it. Or even more than two.